# Javascript .js file to variable

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying the following to pull in a json formatted file into a JS variable
(the json file is correct json).

```
var data;
$.getJSON('../data/data.js', function(json){
    data = json;
});
console.log(data);
```

The result is:

```
undefined
```

When I console.log inside the `$.getJSON` function I do get the results.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: `getJSON` is asynchronous. `data` will be `undefined` when you log it. Add a `console.log()` to the callback function and you'll see that it fires asynchronously, with a delay.

Comment: @JayBhatt getScript() also executes the data, but since it's json isn't that a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

The file seems to be received successfully. However, your problem is that the callback function is run asynchronously, so data is value is not defined when it is logged.

Solution:

```
var processFile = function (fileData) {
    // do processing here.
}


var data;
$.getJSON('../data/data.js', function(json){
    data = json;
    processFile(data);
});
```

Comment: It's not `null` it's `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you, But i need to use the data afterwards.. How can I do that? the console.log is just for testing. thanks

Comment: It is not a concern here, the objective is that no value is assigned to data. However, edited the answer.

Comment: @Notflip you can handle the response in a function where one of the parameters is the data received (the JS file). See updated answer

Comment: Hmh still not working, I can process the data in the processFile function, but I want to be able to use the data in the whole file.. which is not working, thank you for your time so far!